# Oracle SQL combine non-duplicate results of multiple queries

Tags: sql, oracle

I have three queries all selecting the same attribute from the same table and same `WHERE` clause, but each joining on a different table. Unfortunately I can't create tables in this database.

What I'm trying to achieve is to not have overlapping results between the three queries display in the results. In other words, if query 1 and query 2 are combined, only those results from query 2 that **have not** been returned in query 1 should be combined into the output.

Sample of two queries:

```
  SELECT UNIQUE C.color
    FROM colors C INNER JOIN markers M ON M.color = C.color
   WHERE M.color NOT LIKE 'g%'
     AND M.hue NOT LIKE 'b%'
ORDER BY C.color ASC; /*this returns 2744 rows in my db*/

  SELECT UNIQUE C.color
    FROM colors C INNER JOIN pencils P ON P.color = C.color
   WHERE P.color NOT LIKE 'g%'
     AND P.hue NOT LIKE 'b%'
ORDER BY C.color ASC; /*this returns 4192 rows in my db*/
```

If query 1 returns: Cyan, Orange, Purple
And query 2 returns: Gold, Orange, Purple

Then the results I'm hoping for would be: Cyan, Gold, Orange, Purple (aka UNIQUE modifier) instead of: Cyan, Gold, Orange, Orange, Purple, Purple

<s>**Edit:** There was a suggestion to use `UNION` to combine the two since it returns distinct results. So I made the necessary syntax changes but the results only returned 195 rows. This seems odd to me. I would've expected at least 2744 rows (output of query 1) + whatever unique values are returned from query 2 that were not already in query 1.</s>

**Edit 2:** Nevermind `UNION` clearly worked! I was doing a `COUNT` on each individual query without using `DISTINCT`. Thank you to whomever replied with the answer.

Comment: can you provide sample input and ouptut because a union would do it

Comment: `UNION` worked. I had syntax of `SELECT UNIQUE COUNT(C.Color).....` which was giving the count of all results not just distinct ones and that's where I got confused. Thank you for the solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use  a simple union for it:

```
 SELECT UNIQUE C.color
    FROM colors C INNER JOIN markers M ON M.color = C.color
   WHERE M.color NOT LIKE 'g%'
     AND M.hue NOT LIKE 'b%'
ORDER BY C.color ASC; /*this returns 2744 rows in my db*/
union
  SELECT UNIQUE C.color
    FROM colors C INNER JOIN pencils P ON P.color = C.color
   WHERE P.color NOT LIKE 'g%'
     AND P.hue NOT LIKE 'b%'
ORDER BY C.color ASC; /*this returns 4192 rows in my db*/
```